dotnet Linux build fails because project has build events written for cmd
I'm trying to build a .Net project - that was created on Windows - using the Linux dotnet-core SDK (8.0.404), but the build fails because the project has pre/post build events that are written in Windows cmd.exe ("batch scripting") syntax:
$ dotnet build Project
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  /usr/bin/sh: 3: /tmp/MSBuildTempodeda/tmp6707ffb923be418d8a5720ef9ed70268.exec.cmd: Syntax error:
    "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
/snap/dotnet-sdk/254/sdk/8.0.404/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1426,5): error MSB3073:
    The command " [/home/odeda/path/to/project/Project.csproj]
/snap/dotnet-sdk/254/sdk/8.0.404/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1426,5): error MSB3073:
             SOME BATCH SYNTAX WITH IF CLAUSES [/home/odeda/path/to/project/Project.csproj]
/snap/dotnet-sdk/254/sdk/8.0.404/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1426,5): error MSB3073:
    " exited with code 2. [/home/odeda/path/to/project/Project.csproj]

Build FAILED.

the .Net SDK obviously tries to run the build events - that were created to run on the local Windows "system shell" - with the Linux POSIX shell, which as expected doesn't work (its not even close to being a similar syntax, which is yet another reason Microsoft's claim of Windows POSIX compatibility is a lie).
Is there a way to set up different build event scripts to be run on Windows vs. Linux? I didn't find anything appropriate in the MSBuild documentation.

You can add a Condition attribute to the Exec item to determine the current OS. On Windows, the value of the $(OS) variable is Windows_NT, while on Linux it is Unix (I tested on Ubuntu, if this value doesn't match, try to execute echo $(OS) without a condition).
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="echo !!!!Windows!!!!" Condition="'$(OS)'=='Windows_NT'" />
    <Exec Command="echo !!!!Unix!!!!" Condition="'$(OS)'=='Unix'" />
</Target>


The scripts still have to be trans-scribed to whatever you are able to run, though. Would be cool to be able to have #!/bin/env cmd but I haven't seen that, yet.

Do you mean running the same command on both OS? It's able to run shell scripts on Windows.

That way round would be way easier and currently feasable, yes.

In current versions of MSBuild, you can also use Condition="'$([System.OperatingSystem]::IsWindows())'" and  Condition="!'$([System.OperatingSystem]::IsWindows())'". See System.OperatingSystem property functions.

I was a bit confused about the syntax - the problem is in the .csproj file where the events are configured as <Project>...<PropertyGroup><PreBuildEvent>#cmd-code... , but setting <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' "> solved the problem. Thank you!

@Guss That sounds like a .vcxproj (C++) and not a .csproj (C#). In a C# .csproj project, the pre and post build event targets are added as the example in the answer shows.

@JonathanDodds I don't know what to say to that - as can be seen in the OP, the errors definitely come from a .csproj file, and the project is most definitely C# code and not C++.
